# sql-server: update two tables using text boxes and datagridvew

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to create a billing form. I have two tables in sql-server. The text boxes should insert the date to table 1 and datagridview to table 2.

I am not getting any errors but I have a text box which generates auto number, and under each number there should be multiple rows in datagridview.

The code below is saving only the last row in the table. [This is my billing form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP3aF.png)

Can you check the code and tell me what is wrong?

```
        con = new SqlConnection("data source=localhost;initial catalog=testDb;integrated security=true");
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select CashirReport.ReportId,CashirReport.ReportNumber,CashirReport.ReportDate ,
            CashirReportDetails.SerialNumber,
            CashirReportDetails.RefDetails,CashirReportDetails.Amount from CashirReport
            inner join CashirReportDetails on CashirReport.ReportId=CashirReportDetails.ReportDetailsNumber", con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);


    }

    private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvDetails.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into CashirReport(ReportDate,Total)values(@ReportDate,@Total);
                insert into CashirReportDetails(SerialNumber,RefDetails,Amount)values(@SerialNumber,@RefDetails,@Amount)",con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtDate.Value.Date;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtAmount.Text;


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNumber", dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RefDetails", dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Just put `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` inside the for loop:

```
    private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvDetails.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into CashirReport(ReportDate,Total)values(@ReportDate,@Total);
                insert into CashirReportDetails(SerialNumber,RefDetails,Amount)values(@SerialNumber,@RefDetails,@Amount)",con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtDate.Value.Date;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtAmount.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNumber", dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RefDetails", dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);

            //inside the for loop
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried that one it is generating a new number for each row in gridview

Comment: so try to make your question more clear. give example of data and what you want to insert into database

Comment: It is like user will enter date and report number will be generated automatically, under same report number there will be multiple row in grid view , it is something like invoice